# Is Schema.org Store appropriate for online stores?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

I have an online store and I have added a Schema.org [Website](https://schema.org/WebSite) entity to its JSON-LD structured data. The store also has a brick and mortar store. So I was wondering whether it would be also appropriate to add a [Store](https://schema.org/Store) entity to the structured data?
Can the Website and the Store entity co-exist and would it be beneficial?

Comment: Your title (`Store` for web shops?) seems to ask a different question than your body (`Store` together with `WebSite`?), no?

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, Please add [LocalBusiness](https://schema.org/LocalBusiness) schema - this will work better ;). As for Website, please check information about [website enhancements](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/enhance-site).

Also, I would go to [Google for schema docs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data), as not all structured data gives any result. Structured data influences on how your website looks like in search results. (Or how Search Engine shows information in the snippets).

Please check information for [LocalBusiness at Google Developers portal](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-businesses). And it will be awesome if you add schemas for your products in the store, this will have a huge impact, I think.